# npm package installation over proxy ends in error 407

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, proxy, .npmrc

I am trying to install some npm packages on my enterprise pc. Lately it worked fine, but all of the sudden me and a college received a cb() error with the logs being:

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.3
4 verbose npm-session 997cea016022b883
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall <censored>@0.0.0
7 info lifecycle <censored>@0.0.0~preinstall: <censored>@0.0.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 27ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 1ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 warn read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
16 http fetch GET 407 https://<censored> 122ms
17 timing npm Completed in 2340ms
18 error cb() never called!
19 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
20 error <https://npm.community>
```

I have to use a proxy which is being defined in the .npmrc (checked multiple times if right url). Here is my .npmrc

```
always-auth=true
strict-ssl=false
proxy=http://<user censored>:<password censored>@<censored>.com:8080/
https-proxy=http://<user censored>:<password censored>@<censored>.com:8080/
```

As in log[16] I receive a 407 (Proxy Authentication Required) I initially thought my proxy url might be wrong in the npmrc, but that is not the case. Does anyone have a clue why this could happen?